# How do I use @Hostbinding in Angular to style a dynamic component?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular2-hostbinding

I'm currently working on an Angular project that creates a bunch of dynamic components and I want each one to have a different color based upon the results of a call to a service that it makes on initialization. The code for the component is as follows:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-step',
  templateUrl: './step.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./step.component.css'],
  providers: [DisplayService, MessageService]
})
export class StepComponent implements OnInit {

//a bunch of other functions and a constructor

findSolutions(defect: Defect): void {
    //this is where I make the call to the service
    this.defectService.getSolutions(defect, this.displayService).subscribe(solutions => {
      if(solutions[0] === undefined) {
          //HERE I want to change the back-ground color of .boxed (element 
          //in the style file) to yellow
        }
        else if(solutions !== undefined) {
          //HERE I want to change the back-ground color of .boxed to green
        }
    });
  }

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.findSolutions(this.defect);
  }
}
```

Can someone help me figure out how to use HostBinding?

Comment: Why don't you use NgClass to add or remove a class dependant on a component property bool or value?

Comment: @DarrenStreet Oh yah, that works. If you want to submit it as an answer, I'll give it the check so you can get the reputation for it lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use NgClass to add or remove a class dependant on a component property bool or value?